# Show data from db into checkbox

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, checkbox

I've a SQL Database with only one table for my checkbox : name(string) and value(boolean).
At this time, I show a list of checkbox for test, but it's not from my db.

```
  public class Model{
    String name;
    int value; /* 0 -&gt; checkbox disable, 1 -&gt; checkbox enable */

    Model(String name, int value){
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public int getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }

}

   // MainActivity 

    ListView lv;
    Model[] modelItems;
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        modelItems = new Model[5];
        modelItems[0] = new Model("pizza", 0);
        modelItems[1] = new Model("burger", 1);
        modelItems[2] = new Model("olives", 1);
        modelItems[3] = new Model("orange", 0);
        modelItems[4] = new Model("tomato", 1);
 //Custom Adapter is a Java Class for Show ListView with Checkbox
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, modelItems);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Can you reconstruct your question. Are you trying to have a listview populated by checkboxs with data coming from a database? If so what is the problem you are facing

Comment: Yes that's it ! :) I dont know how I can do this. i think it's a SQL request like SELECT name,value from item. And after take data how i can stock data into checkbox ? I'm totally lose